# delete row using integer where clause?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i have database and i want to delete row using _id column value which contain integer value.

this is my data base:

```
public class ContactDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="totalContact.db";
    public static final  String TABLE_NAME="mecontact";
    public static final  String NAME="name";
    public static final  String PHONE="phone";
    public static final  String UID="_id";


    public ContactDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("create table mecontact" +
                    "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, phone text)");
        }catch(android.database.SQLException e){
                System.out.println("table create nhi ho rha");
        }
    }
 public void deleteContact(String d,int pos){
        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    {String.valueOf(pos) });
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id  =  ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(pos)});

        db.close();
    }
}
```

i use lot of query for example:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, UID + "= ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(pos) });
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "name = ? '" + d + "'"  + "  AND _id ? = ", new String[] {String.valueOf(pos) } );
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "name = ? AND _id = " + pos, new String[]{ d });
```

but no one is working i'm so upset plese help.

Comment: First thing, you don't need the `{String.valueOf(pos) });` line above `db.delete()`

Comment: Are you having any errors or anything in the Logcat?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob no error and also no change whith table

Comment: @SQLiteNoob when i use query only for the string condition it will work fine but in case of integer no change with my table

Comment: is there a valid int being passed in the constructor? Ie does `pos` have a value equal to a row number in the db?

Comment: yes pos have integer value and i also check by putting real integer value on the place of pos in the query but nothing will change

Comment: `db.delete(TABLE_NAME, UID + "= ? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(pos)});` is literally the same line I use. I would have to guess that the value doesn't exist in the db.

Comment: `db.delete(TABLE_NAME, UID + "= 1");`  doesn't work when you have 1 record?